# Save As Template

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word, save-as

I am trying to streamline a series of documents as follows:

1. Macro-Enabled Template Base Document
2. The document is overwritten with project-specific information that will be repeated across various documents based on the specific template
3. A button is clicked to run a macro which deletes the button from the base template and prompts the user to save the document as a new template
4. The new template can be used to create a series of documents without the need to insert generic project information each time

The code works to delete the button, and save the document, but **not** as a Macro Enabled **template**.

Despite the code showing wdFormatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled, each time it is run a Macro-Enabled Document (.docm) is saved.

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Jon

```
Sub Save_New_Template()

    Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1


Dim i As Long, strFileName As String
While i = 0
  i = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show
  If i <> 0 Then
    strFileName = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).SelectedItems(1)
    strFileName = Split(strFileName, ".dotm")(0) & ".dotm"
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=strFileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled
  End If
Wend
 

End Sub`
```

Comment: Please click the edit link below the question and provide more details. Explain exactly what isn't working and where it goes wrong.

Comment: Hi @TimothyRylatt, questions revised.

Comment: When I run the code in your question I get a macro enabled template. Every time. I suggest that you step through your code and check at what point the file extension is incorrect.

Comment: The line that sets the file extension is pointless if the user chose the correct file type and will result in some odd looking file names if they didn't. But it still results in a file of the desired type.

Comment: Hi Timothy, I was looking to restrict the option to template only. Ideally, I want there to be no option other than to save it as a template. That's not working my end, it's saving it as a macro-enabled doc, not a template.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see which line is failing to produce the correct file name?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt, stepping doesn't help. The second step is the save dialogue box which gives all save options. If I could have a line of code in there which gives only the option for macro template I'd be free and clear.

Comment: It is not possible to restrict the file type in the SaveAs dialog. Your only option is to force the extension and file type as you are currently doing, albeit rather crudely. Stepping through code (executing it one line at a time using F8) is a fundamental tool in debugging code. You need to do it to find which line of code is giving you the wrong result. It is not possible to reproduce your issue using the code and information in your question.

Comment: Your whole approach seems wrong to me. Once should use templates to create *documents*, not more *templates*. Moreover, any document created from a macro-enabled template can be saved in the docx format and still have the full functionality of the macros in the template.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt, restricting file types is possible in Excell VBA, is it not the same for Word?

Comment: @macropod, I understand this is somewhat unconventional, but the process has solid logic. The base template is to be used across all new contracts. Once a new contract is created, the base template is to be updated with project-specific information to be then saved as a new project-specific template, from which multiple project-specific documents can be created. I'd be happy to hear of an alternative solution to this problem.

Comment: GetSaveAsFilename is unique to Excel.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt, therein lies the route of my problem I guess. I was developing this based on my understanding of Excell VBA. This is my first venture into Word VBA. I guess then that the workaround is to rely on users to select a macro template when saving the file? Is there anything I can add to the code to prompt the user to save as a macro enabled tempplate?  A msg box perhaps?

Comment: The code you have will suffice if you make it less crude to avoid results such as "filename.docx.dotm". I would use InStrRev to find the file extension separator, check if the extension is correct and replace it if necessary.

Comment: Thanks @TimothyRylatt, would you mind updating the code to show where this is applied please? I do have an issue where the user cannot cancel. Is it possible to add a line to exit if canceled?

Comment: It would replace the line where you use the split function. It is your use of While ... Wend that is preventing the user from cancelling. Just delete those two lines.